# How to update the Wxpython statusbar with run-time data streaming in another *.py file

Tags: events, wxpython, runtime, statusbar, python-multithreading

my project has many python files,and right now the problem is when I clicked button in Main-UI interface,it will invoke some function in another python file(sub-program),and i need all the running status in sub-program will also be updated in main-UI,how do i accomplish this?
The thing i can try so far i known is using socket,but i want to know do you guys have any other good ideas on this?
The code like this:
1. Main-UI:

```
import wx,time
from threading import Thread
from path import basicTest
EVT_RESULT_ID = wx.NewId()
def EVT_RESULT(win, func):
  win.Connect(-1, -1, EVT_RESULT_ID, func)
class ResultEvent(wx.PyEvent):
  def __init__(self, data):
    wx.PyEvent.__init__(self)
    self.SetEventType(EVT_RESULT_ID)
    self.data = data
class TestThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self, wxObject):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.wxObject = wxObject
    self.start()
  def run(self):
```

## this masked sub-script can run,but what i want to do is to replace it with invoking from another python file

```
'''
    for i in range(6):
      time.sleep(1)
      wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent(i))
'''
    data = basicTest().run(10)
    wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent(data))

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tester")
    panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Start Test")
    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
    EVT_RESULT(self, self.updateStatus)
  def onButton(self, event):
    TestThread(self)
    btn = event.GetEventObject()
    btn.Disable()
  def updateStatus(self, msg):
    t = msg.data
    self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Sequence %i running.." %t)
    self.btn.Enable()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp()
  frame = MyForm().Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

2. sub-script:

`import time
 class basicTest():
    def run(self,inter):
      for i in range(inter):
        return i
        time.sleep(1)`

As list above and also i known that the main UI only updated when the sub-script finished,it's not run-time refresh from another sub,can anyone help me, very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I would just leave the long running code in its thread. Then you can have wxPython start the thread. In your thread's `run` method, just use one of wxPython's thread-safe methods to call your UI. I would recommend `wx.CallAfter` or 'wx.PostEvent'.

Once you have that done, then you just execute the necessary method in your main UI.